# Is there an easy way to match the rows of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to identify synchronous activities for id during time t. Basically I would like to know the activities that are common during time t based on gender. Uncommon activities I replaced with 0.

Input

```
id     DMSex       t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6 
12       M         12  12  12  12  12  17
12       F         10  13  12  12  12  17
```

Output:

```
id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6 
12   0   0  12  12  12  17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_at(-1, as.numeric) %>%
  summarise_at(-1, ~ case_when(n_distinct(.) != 1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ first(.)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 7
     id    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    12     0     0    12    12    12    17
```

You could also replace the `n_distinct(.) != 1` with `!all(. == .[1])`, `!any(duplicated(.))` or `sd(.) != 0`, among others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data.table approach.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,lapply(.SD,function(x){
     if(length(unique(x)) > 1) {0}
     else{unique(x)}}),
  by = id,.SDcols = c(setdiff(names(data),"DMSex"))]
#   id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
#1: 12  0  0 12 12 12 17
```